# Tenant specific Resilience Configuration

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We want to provide options to customers to configure resilence like for circuit breaker configuration. Kindly let us know is there a way we can provide tenant-specific configuration in cloud SDK.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. What have you tried? What have you got? Please ensure you include the [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi @Sagar Gupta, yes please add more context to your question. Let me refer you to the SAP Cloud SDK docs about resilience for a first glimpse: https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/resilience/resilience Without further details and more concrete questions it's difficult to help you. Please point out what you tried and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Hi Team,
As I read the resilience multi-tenancy approach, but here we want to provide an option to tenants to change configurations like for CircuitBreaker configurations like "slidingWindow", "slowCallThreshold" etc.. Here we need some way we can provide provision to tenants to change this setup if possibile.

Comment: Our Javadoc explains which features of the CircuitBreaker configuration the SDK exposes: https://help.sap.com/doc/09e785cb1f214f36be539d2059cc2cb1/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/resilience/ResilienceConfiguration.CircuitBreakerConfiguration.html

Comment: I interpret your last answer so that slidingWindow and slowCallThreshold are only examples of more things. Can you please elaborate more on your original question? There is not enough information to help you properly. Have you tried something already or is this only a theoretical question?

Answer (score 0):

We have already tried the multi-tenant approach for achieving resilience. But for our scenario we are use resilient approach even for customer systems (op systems) where the customers are asking to provide flexibility to decide parameters like slowCallRate etc according to their landscape. We want to know if we need to externalise the configuration for CircuitBreaker to customers so that they can alter some values as per their setup, how can we do it?

Thanks
Sagar

Comment: Hi Sagar, I understand that you want to let the Circui tBreaker configuration parameters be configurable at runtime. The answer if this is possible depends on how the Circuit Breaker is being configured in the code: Does this question refer to Circuit Breakers which are configured inside Cloud SDK/outside your app or do you build this Circuit Breaker configurations yourself in your own app code?
Please elaborate what kind of requests (OData, SOAP; which service is called?) you refer to.

Comment: This is for OData request and we want to know if we can configure it for CloudSDK circuit breaker.

Comment: Hi Sagar, the standard OData request of the Cloud SDK does not leverage the resilience capabilities out-of-the box. You have to explicitly wrap your OData call in the `ResilienceDecorator` to achieve this. That is, **you** as the app developer have full control to build and hence to configure the `ResilienceConfiguration` as per your needs. That means you can also influence to what extent you expose the resilience configuration parameters again further to your customers (like on a UI or something).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to call the [SAP BusinessPartner service](https://api.sap.com/api/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/resource) (OData V2) for the destination as configured in your *CloudFoundry Destination Service* with the name "MyDestination".

Then your code would look like this with [SAP Cloud SDK](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/):

```java
HttpDestination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("MyDestination").asHttp();
BusinessPartnerService service = new DefaultBusinessPartnerService();

List<BusinessPartner> items = service
  .getAllBusinessPartner()
  .top(10)
  .executeRequest(destination);
```

If you want to apply resilience features to the OData request, then it would look like this:

```java
HttpDestination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("MyDestination").asHttp();
BusinessPartnerService service = new DefaultBusinessPartnerService();

ResilienceConfiguration configuration = ResilienceConfiguration.of("ten-businesspartners");

List<BusinessPartner> items = ResilienceDecorator.executeSupplier(
  () -> service.getAllBusinessPartner().top(10).executeRequest(destination),
  configuration);
```

You can customize the instance of `ResilienceConfiguration` to your needs at runtime, e.g. thresholds for the circuit breaker, like this (with default values):

```java
ResilienceConfiguration.of("ten-businesspartners")
    .circuitBreakerConfiguration(ResilienceConfiguration.CircuitBreakerConfiguration.of()
        .waitDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .closedBufferSize(10)
        .failureRateThreshold(50)
        .halfOpenBufferSize(5)
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we will check this and confirm.

Comment: Please let me know in the comment chain in case this was not successful.